# Is CPU Intel Core i5 8Th generation quade-core enough for Visual Studio system requirements?

Tags: visual-studio, cpu

Microsoft says that minimum CPU requirement for visual studio 2017 should be 1.8 GHz Dual-core and for Visual Studio 2019 it should be 1.8 GHz Quad-core.

I want to know if CPU Intel Core i5 8th generation with Quad-core, 6 MB Cache and frequency between 1.6 GHz to 3.4 GHz enough for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 or not?

I just use these items:

- Visual Studio Community version.
- Programming on WPF and ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core
- SQL Server LocalDb.
- XAMARIN

Microsoft recommended 1.8 GHz base frequency, But I want to know is 1.6 GHz enough for me base on the features I use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It should work just fine. Since an 1.8GHz Quad Core CPU is required at minimum.

Intel Core i5-8250U can go up to 3.4 GHz and has quad cores. The cpu usage and speed will increase when you launch Visual Studio 2019 and you won’t have a problem.

[Intel Core i5-8250U Specifications](https://ark.intel.com/products/124967/Intel-Core-i5-8250U-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-40-GHz-)

[Visual Studio 2019 System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/system-requirements)